# Boolean value from the database MYSQL android studio

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have this code
PHP:

```
    <?php
    $premium=$_POST['premium'];
    $con=mysqli_connect("My datas");
    $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `Login` WHERE `premium`='$premium'");
     if($premium==1)
    {
        echo "Cont Premium";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Cont NonPremium";
    }
    ?>
```

And this is in my java class:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, PREMIUM_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if(response.trim().equals("Cont Premium")){
                        addCar.setText("ADAUGA MASINA");
                    }else{
                        addCar.setText("DOAR PERSONALUL AUTORIZAT");
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            }){};

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

But every time the button text (addCar it's a button) it's the same (DOAR PERSONALUL AUTORIZAT). What it's wrong and how can I fix this?

This is my database structure : 
[image]

Comment: first check how the booleans are stored in the database. (Caution, spoiler: They are not stored as boolean)

Comment: What do you mean? Look at edit please (Booleans are stored with 1 and 0 )

Comment: `premium   tinyint(1)` is what I mean.  But looks like you already know that it is stored like a tinyint, ok. But now I see that you don't do anything with your sql query result. Also how do you pass `$_POST['premium']` parameter to the server? If iyou don't pass it as `1`, then you will always get `Cont NonPremium`

Comment: But also if I pass it as 1 I will always get Cont Premium ..  And I think this is what you ask `public static final String PREMIUM_URL = "http://parcaridb.dx.am/premium.php";`

Comment: ok, then I was right. Just carefully read your PHP code once more. It returns you what you have passed as parameter regardless of what is in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the bool value of premium to set the if/else responde on the class? Like:

```
if (response.trim().equals(#premium == 0))
{
   addCar.setText("ADAUGA MASINA");
}
else
{
   addCar.setText("DOAR PERSONALUL AUTORIZAT");
}
```

Comment: Maybe.. But what it's #premium? How can I associate ?